# iOS 8 & Cordova: App requests push notification permissions immediately on first launch

Tags: cordova, ios8, ios-permissions

**Update:** Still getting this problem in the launched / GM version of iOS 8.

My Cordova app (version 3.5.0-0.2.7), in iOS 7, requests push permissions from the user when I try to register the device.

Now, in iOS 8 (beta 5, with Xcode beta 7), it requests push permissions the moment the app is opened for the first time. This is not good, since users will often deny permission if the request isn't given some context.

From what I can tell, iOS 8 now lumps remote push notifications and local notifications together into the same permission request, whereas previously, local notifications weren't separately requested. (Source: [1](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/50722-ios-8-corona-apps-ask-for-push-notification-approval/), [2](http://www.pocketgamer.co.uk/r/iPhone/iOS+8/news.asp?c=60449)). Is it possible that Cordova is requesting local notification permissions behind the scenes at launch, and now, in iOS 8, that's getting surfaced to the user?

The only Cordova plugin I have that seems related is PushPlugin. (Not using any local notification plugins.)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Local notifications never needed any permissions and from what I've seen they dont need permission now either - its only push notifications that require permission from the user

Comment: Are you sure? I keep on seeing references online to local notifications now requiring permission in iOS 8 ([example 1](http://www.knowing.net/index.php/2014/07/03/local-notifications-in-ios-8-with-xamarin/), [example 2](http://www.pocketgamer.co.uk/r/iPhone/iOS+8/news.asp?c=60449))

Comment: And, here's an excerpt from a transcript from one of the WWDC talks this year: "So, in iOS 8, regardless of whether your app is going to display remote user notifications or local user notifications, your app must first register to use those notifications.

And this is going to result in an alert that is going to be presented to the user, asking them if it's OK for your app to present notifications to them." ([Source](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/713))

Comment: Does this mean you can't even update a badge count without user permission? A badge on the app icon is hardly invasive.

Answer (score 0):

in the file AppDelegate + notification.m try commenting the line where it sets badge number to 0 in the method applicationDidBecomeActive